# How to turn a referenced class from another project into a DataContract?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I have two projects; one is a WCF service and one is a C# project. In my WCF project, I am using a method from my C# project; that methods returns a List. ClassA is defined in the C# project, so I have a reference in my WCF service to my C# project. I want to turn ClassA into a DataContract. Is there a better way than copying the file of ClassA over to the WCFProject and smacking the DataContact tags over it?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't copy the file but instead create a `ClassAMessage` class that only exposes the bits of `ClassA` that you need in your Data Contract.

Comment: If I wanted the entire ClassA exposed, would I still create ClassAMessage class and expose everything or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be open to applying the decorations in the original ClassA?

Comment: I thought about that, but I wasn't sure if it was necessary since the C# project doesn't need it to be a DataContract.

Comment: I had the same dilemma as you. I ended up decorating the non-wcf class even though it seemed messy and unnecessary. The advantage was having one class to manage instead of multiple versions. 

However, I knew this was going to be used by a WCF service initially, and possibly by other non-service applications later.

Comment: I might end up doing that if no better recommendations comes along.

Comment: The DataContractAttribute is in the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace. It is in no way tied to WCF. Its just defining how you want the class serialized. This is not "messy". It is in fact a clean separation of concerns.